# What is background risk or baseline risk?

Tags: self-study, epidemiology

What is background risk or baseline risk? and also what does APE refer to in EBM?

Comment: Some more context would be helpful

Comment: Suggested comment (anonymous user): APE stands for Attributable Proportion among the Exposed.  It is described in "Understanding Evidence in Health Care" by Doi, S.  (ISBN 978-1-4202-5669-7).

Answer (score 6):

In the context of epidemiology, baseline risk is the incidence of the disease, or outcome of interest, in the population.

EBM=Evidence Based Medicine ? I don't know what APE is. Maybe Advanced Professional Education or APE stands for Attributable Proportion among the Exposed